# Mayor cantidad de letras que no se repiten en Python

Tags: python

La función recibe una palabra y retorna el máximo largo de una subpalabra cuyas letras no estén repetidas.

Ejemplo: recibe: "TATACT" y retorna 3

Explicación: la subsecuencia "TAC" contiene 3 bases no repetidas, también la subsecuencia "ACT"

Esto es lo que intenté hacer:

```
sec1 = input("ingrese una secuencia") 
sec2 = input("ingrese una secuencia") 
def max_subsecuencia(sec1):
    max_largo = 0
dic={}
  if len (sec1)!= len (sec2):
      return False

  else:    
      for x in range (len(sec1)):
        if sec1[x] in dic:
            if dic [sec1[x]] != sec2[x]:
                return False
```

Comment: Supongo que podrías usar un arreglo o un diccionario para guardar las letras que ya aparecieron.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Pero intentaste algo? eso no hace nada.. intentaste contar las letras por lo menos???

Comment: Esta es la quinta pregunta que haces, que tiene el mismo problema. No demuestra un esfuerzo, y tampoco tenemos ninguna respuesta de tu parte a las consultas que te hacemos...

Comment: No se como seguir alguna me podría mostrar como?

Comment: Las preguntas que ya hice me han servido, se como contestarles

Comment: Si te sirvieron, acepta las respuestas. Registrate en el sitio y trabaja para que podamos ayudarte. Quienes respondieron no tuvieron ningun feedback de tu parte. Aprende a usar el sitio.

Comment: Ahí puse el diccionario que ya lo tenia creado

Comment: Buenisimo.. ahora, explica mejor el ejercicio.. porque releyendo (varias veces), me parece que es otra cosa lo que queres...  a que llamas bases??? que es una base??? basciamente lo que buscas es ver si 3 letras seguidas son distintas... porque pedis dos cadenas???

Comment: Pensándolo bien, bajo ese criterio nunca encontrarás una cadena de más de 4 letras de longitud. Porque si planeas utilizarlo con el ADN, solo puedes utilizar 4 letras.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es la secuencia mas larga sin letras repetidas entonces no necesitas dos secuencias. En tu codigo estas comparando sec1 y sec2. Tu enunciado y tu codigo no tienen nada que ver el uno con el otro. Como dice Mateo, si tus secuencias son ADN la subsecuencia mas larga sin letras repetidas sera como maximo de longitud 4

Comment: Creaste otro usuario porque no pudiste registrar este? necesitas ayuda para fusionar los perfiles?

Answer (score 0):

```
sec1 = input( "ingrese una secuencia" ) 

def max_subsecuencia( sec1 ):

       // creamos una variable que guarda el largo de la cadena que recibimos 
       // (para no tener que estar pidiéndole el dato en cada iteración).  
    largo = len( sec1 )
    max_largo = 1

       // el diccionario pasa a ser una cadena
    dic = ""

       // este for modifica el valor de inicio del while
    for ini in range( largo ):
        i = ini 

           // recorremos la cadena
        while i < largo:

               // si la base no está contenida en "dic", la agregamos a "dic" 
               // y luego aumentamos en "1" la variable "i"
            if sec1[ i ] not in dic:
                dic += sec1[ i ]

               // si está contenida, comparamos la longitud de "dic" con "max_largo", 
               // si es mayor, asignamos a "max_largo" el valor de esta y salimos del while
            else:
                if max_largo < len( dic ):
                    max_largo = len( dic )
                break
            i += 1

       // retornamos el valor obtenido
    return max_largo
                    
   // invocamos a la función
print( max_subsecuencia(sec1) )
```

Como te señalan en los comentarios, no tiene sentido pedir dos entradas.

Comment: Los comentarios con # que es python! (ahora me paso a borrar este comentario cuando lo arregles)

Comment: Hola Jabro, esto no es un ejecutable, puedes poner los comentarios como te parezca, es solo para que se diferencie de lo que es código, igual gracias por la acotación.

Comment: Si es válido, pido perdón. Lo tengo en cuenta para la próxima

Comment: Nada por lo que disculparte!!!, de hecho no hay ninguna regla sobre esto, lo mio es una opinión personal.

Answer (score 0):

```
palabra=input("ingrese palabra")

def convertir(palabra:str):
"""Convierto el String ingresado a una lista.
Para aplicar set y así eliminar elementos 
Repetidos"""

 lista=[]
 for element in palabra:
    Lista.append[element]
 lista=set(lista)
 Return len(lista)
"""El anterior código compactado sería:"""

 palabra=input(palabra)

def convertir(palabra:str):
  return len( set([element for element in palabra]))
```